# Try to understand calling process in assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I wrote a very simple program in C and try to understand the function calling process.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void Oh(unsigned x) {
    printf("%u\n", x);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Oh(0x67611c8c);
    return 0;
}
```

And its assembly code seems to be

```
0000000100000f20 <_Oh>:
   100000f20:   55                      push   %rbp
   100000f21:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   100000f24:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
   100000f28:   48 8d 05 6b 00 00 00    lea    0x6b(%rip),%rax        # 100000f9a <_printf$stub+0x20>
   100000f2f:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   100000f32:   8b 75 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%esi
   100000f35:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
   100000f38:   b0 00                   mov    $0x0,%al
   100000f3a:   e8 3b 00 00 00          callq  100000f7a <_printf$stub>
   100000f3f:   89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
   100000f42:   48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
   100000f46:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   100000f47:   c3                      retq
   100000f48:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   100000f4f:   00

0000000100000f50 <_main>:
   100000f50:   55                      push   %rbp
   100000f51:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   100000f54:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
   100000f58:   b8 8c 1c 61 67          mov    $0x67611c8c,%eax
   100000f5d:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   100000f64:   89 7d f8                mov    %edi,-0x8(%rbp)
   100000f67:   48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
   100000f6b:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
   100000f6d:   e8 ae ff ff ff          callq  100000f20 <_Oh>
   100000f72:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   100000f74:   48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
   100000f78:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   100000f79:   c3                      retq
```

Well, I don't quite understand the argument passing process, since there is only one parameter passed to Oh function, I could under stand this

```
100000f58:  b8 8c 1c 61 67          mov    $0x67611c8c,%eax
```

So what does the the code below do? Why rbp? Isn't it abandoned in X86-64 assembly? If it is a x86 style assembly, how can I generate the x86-64 style assembly using clang? If it is x86, it doesn't matter, could any one explains the below code line by line for me?

```
100000f5d:  c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
100000f64:  89 7d f8                mov    %edi,-0x8(%rbp)
100000f67:  48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
100000f6b:  89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
100000f6d:  e8 ae ff ff ff          callq  100000f20 <_Oh>
```

Comment: You forgot to enable optimizations (and possibly turn off frame pointers, but that's normally automatically done) that's why you see garbage code.

Comment: What do you mean "abandoned"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might get cleaner code if you turned optimizations on, or you might not.  But, here’s what that does.

The `%rbp` register is being used as a frame pointer, that is, a pointer to the original top of the stack.  It’s saved on the stack, stored, and restored at the end.  Far from being removed in x86_64, it was added there; the 32-bit equivalent was `%ebp`.

After this value is saved, the program allocates sixteen bytes off the stack by subtracting from the stack pointer.

There then is a very inefficient series of copies that sets the first argument of `Oh()` as the second argument of `printf()` and the constant address of the format string (relative to the instruction pointer) as the first argument of `printf()`.  Remember that, in this calling convention, the first argument is passed in `%rdi` (or `%edi` for 32-bit operands) and the second in `%rsi`  This could have been simplified to two instructions.

After calling `printf()`, the program (needlessly) saves the return value on the stack, restores the stack and frame pointers, and returns.

In `main()`, there’s similar code to set up the stack frame, then the program saves `argc` and `argv` (needlessly), then it moves around the  constant argument to `Oh` into its first argument, by way of `%eax`.  This could have been optimized into a single instruction.  It then calls `Oh()`.  On return, it sets its return value to 0, cleans up the stack, and returns.

The code you’re asking about does the following: stores the constant 32-bit value 0 on the stack, saves the 32-bit value `argc` on the stack, saves the 64-bit pointer  `argv` on the stack (the first and second arguments to `main()`), and sets the first argument of the function it is about to call to `%eax`, which it had previously loaded with a constant.  This is all unnecessary for this program, but would have been necessary had it needed to use `argc` and `argv` after the call, when those registers would have been clobbered.  There’s no good reason it used two steps to load the constant instead of one.

Comment: Hmm, this might be better than my answer (which I was writing while you posted this) ... one point it allocates _16_ bytes to the stack (0x10) and one reason it does that is because the stack must be aligned to 16 bytes in x86_64 (so 16 bytes is the minimum to allocate).

Comment: Whoops, that’s 10 hex, not decimal.

Comment: Well done. Only point I would add is you may see *The %rbp register is being used as a frame pointer, that is, a pointer to the original top of the stack.* -- referred to as the assembly `Function Prolog`. (I know you know, but the OP others may run across the verbiage and not snap to the fact).

Comment: Right.  You notice all references to temporary variables stored on the stack and not in registers are relative to `%rbp`, because that won’t change for the duration of the function call, and the stack pointer might, such as if it needs to push arguments to a call it makes onto the stack.

Answer (score 2):

As Jester mentions you still have frame pointers on (to aid debugging)so stepping through main:

```
0000000100000f50 <_main>:
```

First we enter a new stack frame, we have to save the base pointer and move the stack to the new base.  Also, in x86_64 the stack frame has to be aligned to a 16 byte boundary (hence moving the stack pointer by 0x10).

```
       100000f50:   push   %rbp        
       100000f51:   mov    %rsp,%rbp
       100000f54:   sub    $0x10,%rsp
```

As you mention, x86_64 passes parameters by register, so load the param in to the register:

```
       100000f58:   mov    $0x67611c8c,%eax
```

??? Help needed

```
       100000f5d:   movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
```

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions): "Registers RBP, RBX, and R12-R15 are callee-save registers", so if we want to save other resisters then we have to do it ourselves ....

```
       100000f64:   mov    %edi,-0x8(%rbp)
       100000f67:   mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
```

Not really sure why we didn't just load this in %edi where it needs to be for the call to begin with, but we better move it there now.

```
       100000f6b:   mov    %eax,%edi
```

Call the function:

```
       100000f6d:   callq  100000f20 <_Oh>
```

This is the return value (passed in %eax), xor is a smaller instruction than load 0, so is a cmmon optimization:

```
       100000f72:   xor    %eax,%eax
```

Clean up that stack frame we added earlier (not really sure why we saved those registers on it when we didn't use them)

```
       100000f74:   add    $0x10,%rsp
       100000f78:   pop    %rbp
       100000f79:   retq
```